# Do I need two different applications on Spotify Developer site for an iOS and web client of the same app?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api, reactjs, spotify

Might be answering my own question, but do the apps need different client secrets and different callbacks. And if they do, how do I configure it on Spotify?

Answer (score 1):

The iOS SDK uses the same WebAPI, so authorisation is identical I believe. Therefore, only 1 app and set of credentials required :)
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

Comment: That would be sweet if that were the case, thanks Pete :)

Comment: Can confirm - this is the case.